# OptaPlanner: Config XML not mapped correctly and unresolved dependency (slf4j)

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, optaplanner

Should I read this stack trace as two separate issues?  Seems I didn't map the slf4j dependency correclty?  Why would I have to do that?  Wouldn't that be something inherited from the other project (OptaPlanner)?  I'm working with OptaPlanner and experimenting with a modification to the CloudBalancing project.  When I run the app I get the following:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solverConfigResource
>   (scheduleConfig.xml) does not exist as a classpath
>   resource in the classLoader
>   (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@42a57993).   at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:110)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:87)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:65)
>     at com.eddiefiggie.schedulelogic.App.main(App.java:10)

In addition to the slf4j issue reported, it seems my scheduleConfig.xml isn't mapped properly?  I followed the documentation and thought I was ok.  Maybe the error being reported can be explained to my "green" java mind.

---

EDIT based on:

Modified my POM to include:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also placed my xml config in the correct resources path.

Now I get this stack:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
>   (file:/home/eddiefiggie/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar)
>   to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator WARNING: Please consider
>   reporting this to the maintainers of
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields WARNING: Use
>   --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalling of
>   solverConfigResource (scheduleConfig.xml) fails on line number (8).
>   Maybe the classname on line number (8) is surrounded by whitespace,
>   which is invalid.     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:117)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:87)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:65)
>     at com.eddiefiggie.schedulelogic.App.main(App.java:10) Caused by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot load
>   java class ScheduleEasyScoreCalculator
>   ---- Debugging information ---- message             : Cannot load java class ScheduleEasyScoreCalculator class               :
>   java.lang.Class required-type       : java.lang.Class converter-type
>   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
>   wrapped-converter   :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.JavaClassConverter line
>   number         : 8 class[1]            :
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig
>   required-type[1]    :
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig
>   converter-type[1]   :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   class[2]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
>   required-type[2]    : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
>   version             : 1.4.11.1
>   -------------------------------   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.JavaClassConverter.fromString(JavaClassConverter.java:71)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper.fromString(SingleValueConverterWrapper.java:41)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper.unmarshal(SingleValueConverterWrapper.java:49)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:499)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:425)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:499)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:425)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338)   at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlReader(SolverConfig.java:202)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(SolverConfig.java:176)
>     at
>   org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solverConfigResource (scheduleConfig.xml) does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader

It means there is no file at `src/main/resources/scheduleConfig.xml`.

Often your solver config XML is namespaced, so call something like `createFromXmlResource("org/foo/bar/scheduleConfig.xml")` to look for it at `src/main/resources/org/foo/bar/scheduleConfig.xml"`.

Comment: I edited the opening post following these recommended changes.  See above.

Comment: The first issues is resolved: it found the file. Now there's something invalid in the XML. That's a separate question.

Comment: That gave me the clue I needed.  Thanks!  I didn't point to the correct name space for the class file that implements the EasyScoreCalculator within the XML.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that slf4j warning, add logback-classic to your pom:

```
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

slf4j is just an API. It needs an implementation, which is normally logback, it's sibling project.